# Git diff ignores textconv in submodules

Tags: git, git-diff

My project is structured like so:

```
/project
  - file.json
  - /submodule
    - submodule-file.json
```

Where the `/submodule` directory is a git submodule.

I have set up textconv to do some simple pre-processing of json files for diffing - my local `.git/config` file contains

```
[diff "json"]
    textconv = jq -S .
```

This works great for files in the main project - `git diff file.json` works as expected. But it doesn't work for files in the submodule.

`git diff submodule/submodule-file.json` produces no output at all.

`cd submodule && git diff submodule-file.json` produces a diff without the textconv applied.

I would prefer not to make these settings global, and would be happy if I could have them only apply to the submodule.

Is this possible?

git version 2.26.1

Comment: Is the `[diff ...` section in the local (`.git/config`) or global (`~/.gitconfig`) file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would prefer not to make these settings global, and would be happy if I could have them only apply to the submodule.

Yes, it's buried at the bottom of the description in the docs, but the top-priority source for attributes is the repo-local `.git/info/attributes`, anything specified there overrides any committed attributes and your own defaults.

So find the repos where you want this diff applied, add `\*.json diff=myjson` at the end of an `info/attributes` file you probably have to make, and that'll override any diff specified elsewhere for that repo.

You can find the actual repository for an inited submodule with

```
git -C that/submodule rev-parse --absolute-git-dir
```

or to do them all for example

```
git submodule foreach --quiet --recursive git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir
```

and that's the directory whose `info/attributes` file you want to update.

Comment: Thanks! For future readers, the `myjson` in this answer should correspond to the name of the `diff` block in the top-level `git/config`. In my case this was declared as `[diff "json"]`, so the entry in the submodule's `info/attributtes` was `*.json diff=json`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is expected.

Each submodule is essentially a separate git repo. You are only providing a reference to a particular commit of the child submodule repo from the parent repo. If you checkout a new commit in the submodule, the parent tracks that change, but pretty much everything else takes place as though you switched over to another repo. The submodule commands just repeats the same git command across multiple submodules (maybe even recursively, if you added the flag).

So as LeGEC alluded to in his question in the comments, it matters where you setup the `textconv` statement. If it is in the parent `.git/config` then it won't apply to the submodules. Note also that for security reasons this setting will typically not get pushed up to the remote (or fetched down), so you need to set it up locally in most cases (though you could share a script that will set it up elsewhere).

If you want to make the conversion global, you can add the following to your global (or I think system) `.gitconfig`. You can edit the global with `git config -e --global`:

```sh
[core]
    attributesfile = C:/Users/<home>/.gitattributes
```

My `.gitattributes` file is like:

```
*.csv diff=csv
*.xls diff=unzip
```

**NOTE: No spaces around the `=` signs!! Very important!! :)**

And then back in `.gitconfig` I have:

```
[diff "unzip"]
    textconv = unzip -c -a
[diff "csv"]
    tool = csv
    guitool = csv
[difftool "csv"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "csv"]
    prompt = false
    cmd = code --wait \"$MERGED\"
```

(which uses unzip before diff'ing xls and throws csv's to VS Code)

And it applies globally, including to submodules. That should give you the pattern you need if you are just looking for global application.

Comment: I don't really want this setup globally. In fact I would be happy just having it for the submodule. Is this possible? As far as I can see there's no way to configure these settings for submodules.

Comment: Ooh... good question. Since you don't get a full copy of the .git folder, just a file with references, it might not be possible. I wonder if there is a way to tell git to look at a local .gitconfig file for a particular repo, without doing so in the .git folder of that repo? May want to look up the docs on the attributes file and .gitconfig. Dense reading but you may find the answer.  :)